# Deploy Rule Service in WSO2 EI or Wso2 BRS Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I want to use drools in `WSO2`. I checked WSO2 Business Rules Server and it seems that BRS is now integrated in `EI`. 
How can I deploy `Rule Services` in WSO2 EI?

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 Business Rules server is a discontinued product. If you want to use drools with WSO2 EI, EI has a rule mediator which can be used within a mediation configuration. The rule mediator uses drools underneath. However, the rule mediator does not expose all the functionality available from drools.